# Keep getting "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string"

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class Tugas3 {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String nama;
        int umur,nomor;

        System.out.println("Enter Your Full Name : ");
        nama = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Your Age : ");
        umur = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Input Your Phone Number : ");
        nomor = input.nextInt();
        System.out.printf("Contact : "+nama+" "+umur+""+(char)48+""+nomor);
    }
}
```

so i just want to input 0 number but i keep getting that error message.. any solution?

Comment: Can you include the exact inputs?

Comment: What are you inputting for the phone number?

Comment: Why do you have a input.nextLine() after umur = input.nextInt()?

Comment: I tried running your program. It works fine. I even tried entering 0 for all 3 inputs, still works fine

Answer (score 0):

This will allow any input and evade the `InputMismatchException`, but there's nothing wrong with your original code. The problem is that you are trying to use incorrect inputs to test the Scanner.

```
package test;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tugas3 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nama;
    String line;
    int umur = 0,nomor = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter Your Full Name : ");
    nama = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter Your Age : ");
    line = input.nextLine();
    try{
        umur = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
              System.out.println("Invalid number. Set to 0.");
    }

    System.out.println("Input Your Phone Number : ");
    line = input.nextLine();
    try{
        nomor = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
              System.out.println("Invalid number. Set to 0.");
    }
    System.out.printf("Contact : "+nama+" "+umur+""+(char)48+""+nomor);
    }
}
```